# How to tell browserify to include nodejs' http module?

Tags: node.js, browserify

I am trying to bundle my nodejs app using browserify and every single library works fine appart from the fact that browserify doesnt bundle the http module which is required by express.

I guess it is not being bundled because it is part of nodejs and so it is expected to be available.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think ajax is for Browser(to some extent), what http is to server.

While ajax is used only for requesting, http can be used for both responding to and requesting something.

If Browserify was able to bundle http, it would mean that you could use your browser as a Server, which is not what browsers are designed to do.

So that could be why browserify cannot bundle http.